# Does system time consume allocated quanta for a realtime thread?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, real-time

In a real time thread, the user requests that in a certain period P, their thread gets a minimum number of time quanta Q. I would like to know if the following proposition is true or false on various OS, or is at least conditionally true, depending on the specific call or otherwise: the proposition is

"The time spent in a system call does not count as part of the requested quanta Q."

One can derive from this the conclusion that is the program, for example, signals a condition variable, the onus is on the Operating System to accept the request and return control to the user without reducing the time available for other work. That is, the user pays the costs of making the system call but NOT the cost of performing the requested work.

Clearly, this cannot be the case for some calls, for example a memory request may require the OS to access backup store on the disk, in which case the OS cannot ensure the user gets the memory fast enough.

The converse of the signal case is also pertinent: if the waiting thread is real time, does the OS have to ensure a signal is delivered to it quickly enough to still be able to honour its promise?

The question derives from the following observation: if the real time thread is pre-empted, that's fine as long as the OS returns control fast enough that the client thread get the requested quanta Q. The time spent suspended obvious MUST NOT count in this case.

Comment: Real-time programmers try to avoid making any system calls from their real-time thread, because doing so introduces the risk that the system call will not return quickly enough and will therefore cause the real-time thread to miss its deadline.  The deadline (i.e. the time at which an audio buffer runs out of samples, or the time at which the nuclear fuel rods start to melt down) is the same, regardless of whether any particular activity is said to "count" or not.

Comment: Unless the thread requisitions exclusive use of a CPU there is no choice than to perform a system call. Audio is a good example. After processing a block of data, one has to wait for more data to arrive. Using a spinlock is not viable, because (by assumption) that would require exclusive use of a CPU, because the spinlock consumes allocated quanta, leaving insufficient time to perform the actual work.

Comment: I would not expect system call time to be excluded from my budget; but I would expect preemption/interrupt time to be excluded if the timing requirements were sufficiently lax for my guarantee; otherwise I would expect the preemption / interrupt to be deferred.